# Как сделать функцию "пользователь сейчас набирает сообщение" для простого чата

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, чат

Есть простой чат на ajax и php, я сам более менее понимаю php и не знаю js только то что можно нагуглить.

Можете подсказать пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию как в других чатах или мессенджерах "пользователь сейчас набирает сообщение"...

Пока что я смог найти такое решение:

```
function write_mess(data){
    $('#shoutbox-comment').bind("change paste keyup",function()          
    {                   
        if( $(this).val() === '' ) {     //если поле ввода было очищенно                 
            // alert('empty'); 
            var div = document.getElementById('message_status');
            div.innerHTML = '';   
        }
        if( $(this).val() !== '' ) {     //если начал что то писать в поле ввода              
            // alert('empty'); 
            var div = document.getElementById('message_status');
            div.innerHTML =  my_name+' пишет....';   
        }
    });
}
```

Но это высвечивается только у того кто набирает сообщение, как сделать так, чтобы высвечивалось у всех?

Пока я думаю что можно добавить пункт "write_status" в БД mysql с пользователями и добавить условие, если пользователь набирает сообщение, поменять "write_status = 1", если не набирает (поле для ввода пустое) "write_status = 0".

И потом как то подгружать это через ajax из БД вместе с функцией загрузки всех сообщений, указав что 1 = "имя пользователя"+пишет..., а 2 = ""

```
function load(){
    $.getJSON('load_message.php', function(data) {
        appendComments(data);
        write_mess(data);
        $(".chat").scrollTop(90000);
    });
}
```

Но мне кажется что это не совсем верное решение проблемы и возможно есть более верный и простой вариант.

Понадобился чат на работе который проработает буквально месяц - полтора.

---

Дополнение:

Можете подсказать еще пожалуйста, как мне правильно в ajax обновить данные?
То есть когда человек вводит сообщение, его статус меняется на 1, когда поле для ввода становится пустым статус возвращается к 0-лю.

Пока что пробую делать так, но ничего не выходит, можете подсказать пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

```
   function write_mess(data){
        $('#shoutbox-comment').bind("change paste keyup",function()          
        {                   
            if( $(this).val() === '' ) {     //если поле ввода было очищенно                 
                // alert('empty'); 
                var div = document.getElementById('message_status');
    $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:'write_status.php',
    data:"status=0, id_user=1",
    success:function(responsedata){
           alert(responsedata);

    }
 })   
            }
            if( $(this).val() !== '' ) {     //если начал что то писать в поле ввода              
                var div = document.getElementById('message_status');
        $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:'write_status.php',
        data:"status=1, id_user=1",
        success:function(responsedata){
               alert(responsedata);

        }
     })   
            }
        });
    }
```

Пока что я так понял, нужно сначала записать данные в БД через ajax, а потом через websocket выводить сообщения пользователям если условия соответствуют?

Comment: использовать `ajax` + `wevsocket`. `Ajax` - при вводе в поле будет отправлять  на сервер что сообщение пишется, а сокет будет оповещать об этом нужного пользователя, с которым держиться соединение

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц может всё на websocket? Смысл в ajax как-то пропадает

Comment: странный вопрос. Чат же работает на сокете, как вы без него другим то пользователям отправите что-то реалтайм ?

Comment: Пока что я понял что нужно в ajax записывать данные в БД и через websocket их выводить пользователям, верно?  Или я вообще не так все понял?
И если да, то можете подсказать как это сделать - отправить данные в БД - выше в "дополнении" я написал как пробовал сделать, но у меня не вышло